# Does Python map() allow for indexing?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace

Is there any way to get the indices of a list over which one maps a function?  I've gotten the map to almost work, but I to be able to access specific items in my `long_words` list

```
# full_chunk is a very long string of plaintext (eg:pages from a book)
# long_words is a list of words for which I wish to substitute other things

# works
for x in xrange(len(long_words)):
    full_chunk = full_chunk.replace(long_words[x],str(x))

# doesn't work :(
subber = lambda a,b,c: a.replace(b,c)
map(subber(full_chunk,long_words[long_words.index(x)],long_words.index(x)),long_words)
```

Currently, I just want to be able to substitute for every occurrence of every word of `long_words` that appears in `full_chunk` with the index of said word in the `long_words` list.  For example:

```
# example input
long_words = ['programming','pantaloons']
full_chunk = 'While programming, I prefer to wear my most vividly-hued pantaloons.'

# desired output (which is what the for loop gives me)
print(full_chunk)
'While 0, I prefer to wear my most vividly-hued 1.'
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any more info, and thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), you don't need `map()` at all:

```
>>> long_words = ['programming', 'pantaloons']
>>> full_chunk = 'While programming, I prefer to wear my most vividly-hued pantaloons.'
>>> for i, word in enumerate(long_words):
...     full_chunk = full_chunk.replace(word, str(i))
...
>>> full_chunk
'While 0, I prefer to wear my most vividly-hued 1.'
```

Comment: Just to be sure I understand ````enumerate()````, it seems like this is a bit of a middle-ground between my for loop and mapping, correct?  ````enumerate()```` looks like its main advantage is that I wouldn't need to extract the values from the ````long_words```` list every time.  Is that about right?

Comment: @BenSandeen Not sure what you mean, but basically in Python, you never loop over indexes, you loop through elements: `for element in my_list: print(element)`. Now when you use enumerate, you get the element *and* the index. So you loop through the elements and also get their indexes.

Answer (score 2):

`map` isn't quite suitable here because you want to take the return value of the first call of the function and send it as an argument to the second call, etc down the line. `map` can't chain items in this way (unless you resort to trickery with `global` values or similar), but `map`'s friend [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) can:

```
>>> long_words = ['programming','pantaloons']
>>> full_chunk = 'While programming, I prefer to wear my most vividly-hued pantaloons.'
>>> print reduce(lambda s,(idx,word): s.replace(word,str(idx)), enumerate(long_words), full_chunk)
While 0, I prefer to wear my most vividly-hued 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = map(lambda tt: tt[0] + tt[1], enumerate(arr))
print(list(b)) # [1,3,5,7,9]
```